# What is the difference between a schema and a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don`t really understand what the difference is between a schema and a migration. Is a schema created by running a migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails schema.rb file represents the current state of the database.
It is generated and update when you run migrations with

```
rake db:migrate
```

Schema.rb is used when you do `rake db:test:prepare` or `rake db:schema:dump`, `rake db:schema:load`

Migrations are a convenient way for you to alter your database in a structured and organized manner. [Active Record Migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)